# How to integrate Angular/Apollo Client with graphene-django?

Tags: angular, graphql, relay, apollo-client, graphene-python

Sorry for the noob question. I am new to web development with absolutely no experience with GraphQL, Relay or Apollo. I have just finished a web application with Angular 4  frontend and Django Rest Framework as backend. The app is working fine except for some components which have complex data relationships and deep data nestings requiring multiple server trips to assemble a complete object. Also, I couldn't implement selective field queries for a large number of objects with multiple fields even if I require just the name and id to populate a lookup list. So, I implemented a parallel graphene-django api which I have successfully tested with GraphiQL and Postman. According to Graphene docs, additional features such as filtering are implemented using Relay. My problem is how to make Angular communicate with Graphene since Angular is not compatible with Relay and Apollo Client with Graphene. I searched the web but came across only these ([angular2-relay](https://github.com/angular2-relay/angular2-relay) & [graphql-python-subscriptions](http://graphql-python-subscriptions)) solutions which are either experimental or work in progress. Am I missing something here or is it a dead end ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the apollo library you are referring to https://www.apollographql.com/docs/engine/setup-node.html then it doesn't support python. There may be a way to make it work... but I'm not aware of how that may work.

Also, your second link `graphql-python-subscriptions` is no longer active.

Comment: apollo engine and apollo client are two different things